# Add UITextFields programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

How to add `UITextFields` to swift programmatically?

For example, on the first page, the user is asked about the number of machines. After the user presses the button, I want to create the edit text as much as the machine number entered in the page.

Comment: Do you mean a UITextField right?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/text-fields/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dinamically create an object in your view you should something like this

```
let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45, height: 40))
self.view.addSubview(textField)
```

But I think in your case you should change x and y position using the machine number you entered, so you can create multiple textField

A good way to do this is to use UIStackView

```
let stackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 40))
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stackView.distribution = .fill
stackView.spacing = 10
stackView.axis = .vertical

for i in 0...machine number {
    let textField = UITextField()
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(textField)
}
self.view.addSubview(stackView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly crude method. Add a UIStackView to your storyboard and outlet.

```
@IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

private var listOfUITextFields: UITextFields = []

@objc func confirmNumberOfTextFieldsButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let numberOfTextFields = 5 // get this number from the source

    for _ in 0...numberOfTextFields {
        let newTextField = UITextField()
        // customise textfield

        listOfUITextFields.append(newTextField) // can use this as a reference later

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(newTextField)
    }
}
```